# Javascript web-based key derivation

Tags: key-generation

Is there a website with a key derivation function running entirely in client-side Javascript?

The string which is used to generate the key cannot be seen outside the client.

It shouldn't use a run-of-the-mill hash function like SHA2 but something more suitable like Scrypt, and it should use a large character set, not just A-F0-9.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for SE's Q&A format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth If there are too many possible answers give me one.

Comment: Javascript isn't my area of expertise so I can't offer anything specific, but the question, as stated, is rather broad (what do you mean by "The string which is used to generate the key cannot be seen outside the client"?). Given your high rep on Mathematics.SE, I'm sure you can edit the question to have more context and be more focused.

Answer (score 2):

http://anandam.name/pbkdf2/ - I think this does it. It says demo but I think it does the job.

https://www.dailycred.com/article/bcrypt-calculator - So does this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [javascript-bcrypt](https://github.com/nevins-b/javascript-bcrypt) or [crypto-js](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) for PBKDF2. I don't know any scrypt JS implementations so I don't want to recommend one (you can always Google). While you mention scrypt in your question, I think that bcrypt and PBKDF2 are the most widely used functions.

Comment: I would like it to run in the browser. The point is that I can run it on any computer and recover my passwords. Also large character set.

Comment: I believe that those libraries will run in browsers. Are you using a really old browser or one that has JS disabled? If not, I think you should be fine. Am I mistaken?

Comment: my question said website. Currently online. Thanks for telling me about PBKDF2 though.

Comment: @NaN you could write your own website to do this, too.

Comment: That was my thought too @schroeder.